# How to add if statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a following MySQL with two parameters, $catname and $limit=1.
And it is working fine.

```
SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName 
                   FROM omc_product AS P
                   LEFT JOIN omc_category AS C
                   ON C.id = P.category_id
                   WHERE C.Name = '$catname'
                   AND p.status = 'active'
                   ORDER BY RAND()
                   LIMIT 0, $limit
```

Now I want to add another parameter $order.
$order can be either

> ODER BY RAND()
>
> or
>
> ORDER BY product_order

in the table omc_product.

Could anyone tell me how to write this query please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the criteria for choosing one above the other? O, and: is this related to PHP as well? You should tag it accordingly then.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the comments to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) MySQL 5.0 reference article:

You can `ORDER BY` a dynamic column_name parameter using a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause of the `SELECT` statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `orderby`(IN _orderby VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

  SELECT id, first_name, last_name, birthday
  FROM table
  ORDER BY

  -- numeric columns
  CASE _orderby WHEN 'id' THEN id END ASC,
  CASE _orderby WHEN 'desc_ id' THEN id END DESC,
  -- string columns
  CASE _orderby WHEN 'first_name' THEN first_name WHEN 'last_name' THEN last_name END ASC,
  CASE _orderby WHEN 'desc_first_name' THEN first_name WHEN 'desc_last_name' THEN last_name END DESC,
  -- datetime columns
  CASE _orderby WHEN 'birthday' THEN birthday END ASC,
  CASE _orderby WHEN 'desc_ birthday' THEN birthday END DESC;

END
```